# text not shrinkwrapping, why?

Tags: shrinkwrap

it worked before, until i joined the object the tag (black thing i’m trying to get text on to) is connected to but i did NOT join the tag, it’s separate. before i did that it shrink wrapped just fine. i tried again, and no matter what wrap method or snap mode i use and no matter what combo it won’t work again.
[image]

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: https://file.io/PGebYPJzr2LB this work?

Comment: Apply transforms for both objects. In object mode CTRL A > all transforms

Comment: @jasmine file was deleted....

Comment: thanks gorgious that worked like a charm!!